# How to avoid unnecessary logs using fluentd

Tags: node.js, docker, fluentd

I have implemented **fluentd** logs with **docker**. 
The logs are getting printed by **node** services with the help of

`console.log` or `winston logger` statements.

As you can see below there are un-necessary logs are getting printed.

[image]

How can I avoid this logs?

I want to configure it in such a way that it will only print the logs generated by the node services.

Below is the **.conf** file which I have implemented.

```
<source>
   @type forward
   port 24224
</source>

<match docker.**>
      @type file
      @id output_docker1
      path /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
      symlink_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
      append true
      time_slice_format %Y%m%d
      time_slice_wait 1m
      time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
      buffer_path /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
</match>
<match **>
      @type file
      @id output1
      path /fluentd/log/data.*.log
      symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log
      append true
      time_slice_format %Y%m%d
      time_slice_wait 10m
      time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
      buffer_path /fluentd/log/data.*.log
</match>
```

Please suggest the changes for my problem statement.